# Mostrar imagen en <img> despues almacenarla Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Como puedo mostrar imagen en  despues almacenarla Laravel ?

Guardo la imagen de manera exitosa así:

```
\Storage::disk('usuarios')->put('/fotos_perfil/'.$datos_usuario->dni . "/" . $datos_usuario->dni.".".$extension,  \File::get($file));
```

Como hago para obtener la ruta de esa imagen para mostrarla en una etiqueta  pero sin que nadie mas pueda acceder a esa imagen solo directamente desde la aplicacion web?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por lo que veo, estas guardando la imagen en el storage. Lo que debes hacer es "linkear" tu storage con tu carpeta public con el comando `php artisan storage:link` esto creará una carpeta `storage` en `public`, luego en el blade, puedes usar el helper `asset` por ejemplo:

```
<img src="{{ asset("storage/img.png")}}" />
```

Luego puedes ampliarlo aún más todo haciendo un controlador para las imágenes, y así controlar quién puede ver las (o más cosas, según necesidades)

En el archivo rutas (web.php)

```
Route::prefix("/storage", function() {
Route::get("img/{mi Imagen}", "MyControladorDeImagenes@miMetodo" ) 
})
```

Y en controlador hacer comprobación de sí la imagen existe, sí el usuario tiene permiso de visualizar la imagen, etc...